# Is it safe to delete the directory left over from a .NET install?

Tags: windows-7, windows, .net-framework, .net-4.0

<sup>I might have misapprehended the situation. If so, please edit the question title.</sup>

At some point a directory called **f83db84ff30a71d92e** has been left in my **C:\** folder. It contains a bunch of directories whose names are numbers between 1000 and 3000, a few files and a **setup.exe**. The setup turns out to be an installer for .NET 4.

I don't like unnecessary folders littering my disk root. Can I delete it?

[Directory listing of **f83db84ff30a71d92e**](http://pastebin.com/gcTkhF8c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to delete the folder.

You may have to take ownership of the files and change the permissions to allow you to delete the files and folder.